# Site for html containers templates (shaded divs.. etc) for use in websites?

Tags: html, web

I have graphs, reports or just plain text I want to place in a web page. Instead of sitting on the dull white background, I want them to have some containers around them. I can do plain color backgrounds but I was wondering if there are templates for containers with things like rounded corners, shaded containers, flexible gradients,  drop shadow, ideas for partioning sections of a webpage.

Basically I want a resource that has a wealth of these things instead of me searching across tens of sites hoping to find something. I am a web developer not a designer so I need some ideas and help. While there are lots of whole page templates, I am more specific and want ideas for stuff similar to DotNetNuke containers. (Don't send me to DNN templates)

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you want rounded corners, you CAN do it using CSS.  Here's a good article on it:

http://www.devwebpro.com/25-rounded-corners-techniques-with-css/

Instead of looking around for graphics, why not create simple ones in Photoshop?  All of these "partitions" for your website can easily be done by yourself either by using graphics you create or by some CSS.  (i.e. for drop shadow, you can alter the borders)

If you're not into using Photoshop to create your own graphics, here are two sites for vector graphics--you'll have to dig around a bit.

http://www.vecteezy.com/

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/50-websites-for-free-vector-images-download/